# Prevent Table from Expanding When Content Becomes Bold on Hover

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a table and one of the requirements is for each row to become bold on hover. I have this working but the widths of the columns shift when this occurs.

Is there a way I can prevent this?

```css
 table {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin-top: 0;
    border-spacing: 5px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}

table tr:hover {
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>Cell One</td>
      <td>Cell Two</td>
      </tr>

</table>
```

Specifically, it shifts the contents of the second column to the right on hover. While scrolling down the table, this ends up not looking too great.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to reserve space in advance for the bold text.

In other words, when the row is hovered the text goes bold, which results in a wider table cell. But if each table cell factors in the bold text from the start (i.e., before hover), then the width will remain stable regardless of font weight.

In this answer, the content of the table cell is replicated in the [`title` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title), which is then used to create a bold but invisible version of the content using the [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) pseudo-element.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border-collapse: separate;
}

table tr:hover {
  font-weight: 600;
}


/* new */
td::after {
  display: block;
  content: attr(title);
  font-weight: 600;
  color: transparent;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td title="Cell One">Cell One</td>
    <td title="Cell Two">Cell Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```